# I am not able to toggle all li elements

Tags: javascript, loops, dom

My code:

```
var button = document.getElementById("enter");
var input = document.getElementById("userinput");   
var ul = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];    
var li = document.querySelectorAll("li");

function toggle() {
  li.classList.toggle("done");
}    

li.addEventListener("click", toggle);
    
function inputLength() { 
  return input.value.length;
}


function createListElement() {
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value));
  ul.appendChild(li);
  input.value = ""
}

function addListAfterClick() {
  if (inputLength() > 0) {  
    createListElement();  
  } 
}

function addListAfterPress(event) {
  if (inputLength() > 0 && event.keyCode === 13) {
    createListElement();   
  }  
}

button.addEventListener("click", addListAfterClick);
input.addEventListener("keypress", addListAfterPress);
```

Comment: .done {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

Comment: Did you check if there's any error on console?